# Services.Networks must be a mapping when validating docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Wrote the following compose-docker.yml file and when executing the command

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

in PuTTy receive the following error

```
validating /home/arl114/jenkins/docker-compose.yml: services.networks must be a mapping
```

Used https://www.lambdatest.com/free-online-tools/yaml-validator to validate that it is valid yaml and returned that is valid.

'Compose-docker.yml file'

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
  networks:
    - net
networks:
  net:
```

[image: Here are how folders are setup]

Trying to create docker container for Jenkins image using the yml file configuration. Error received and no docker container created.

Comment: After that the question should be closed/deleted since it looks like a typo error to me.

Comment: The error message seems clear here; also see [the definition of per-service `networks:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks).

Answer (score -1):

here's an example on how to point and create new networks in your compose file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  reverse_proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.8.5
    [...]
    networks:
      - services

  web:
    image: nginx
    [...]
    networks:
      - services

networks:
  services:
```

This last networks part will create a new bridge network (default) and will associate both services reverse_proxy and web to it.

Yet, Docker compose files should be validated through docker, not yaml parsers, please check: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/